# Wordpress maintenance mode

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently working with a charity who have built a new site in Wordpress. My wordpress knowledge is somewhat lacking. We have a volunteer, who apparently works with wrodpress a lot, doing some SEO work on the site who has installed a number of plugins. We have been receiving a number of complaints from visitors saying to the site that it seems to be in maintenance mode a lot. I don't fully understand how maintenance mode works. Is this something could only be triggered by someone making changes? Is this activity logged in any way? We need to establish if the maintenance mode is being triggered by the volunteer, although he insists it's not him, or by a problem with the site.

Any advice would appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Wordpress Maintenance**

Sometimes, you may have the need to put your website into maintenance mode for upgrades. This would make your website temporarily unavailable to public access. You wouldn’t want errors to pop up when you are running important updates in the background, right?

It is not that only developers can cause this even authors or the people posting posts can cause this issue.
REFER: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/7-mistakes-beginner-wordpress-users-make

**He must have been triggered it unknowingly!**

**This is not logged in anywhere.**

Refer this blog for Wordpress mainatainance knowledge
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-maintenance/

Check if this plugin is indtalled https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Reading the Wordpress maintenance blog, it looks like the maintenance mode page can be triggered causing a 503 error. The site is on a fairly cheap shared server package. If the server were under heavy load and site timed out could this also cause the maintenance mode page to be displayed?

Comment: And yes that plugin is installed

Comment: @HuwD Hi, if my answer is correct, please mark it as answer.